How to know if the specified file is in my P4CLIENT's view?
I have a script that reads the file path from the terminal. In the script, I checked if the file was in the P4 client's view. But I want to get rid of error messages. I am using p4 have. Redirecting the output of the run to the file or dumping the command output in some variable does not work. I see an error message in any-case.

You might like:
p4 -F %depotFile% have FILE

which will give you the depot file path if any, and no output at all if there isn't one.
The -F global option works with any command and allows you to override the standard message formatting.  If you run p4 -e have you'll see that when you have a file, you get a message with the %depotFile% parameter, and if you don't, you get an error message with a different set of parameters.  Overriding the formatting so that you only ever print the depotFile will implicitly hide the error that you don't want to see.

Thanks for answer. This is exactly what i wanted to get!
